# How to resolve multiple conflicts in the same file differently using terminal on Mac?

Tags: svn, terminal, merge-conflict-resolution

I have this conflicts which are being shown when am trying to merge my code from trunk to branch.
In this file there are multiple conflicts which are arising and i need to resolve each conflicts separately. I am quite new to using SVN and i am using terminal to commit my code.
Here's the conflicts :

```
    Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit, (r) resolved,
            (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
            (s) show all options: dc      
    @@
            }

          } // end of whilefor loop for condition
    <<<<<<< MINE (select with 'mc') (1571,3)

          if(!ifScriptForPrimitiveFactFields.isEmpty()) {
            ifScriptForPrimitiveFactFields += " && (" + ifVerScriptForPrimitiveFactFields + " || hasChanged )";
    ||||||| ORIGINAL (1575,6)

          if (ifScriptForPrimitiveFactFields != null && !ifScriptForPrimitiveFactFields.isEmpty()) {
            if (rule != null && rule.isTriggerApprovalsOnValuesChange() && ifVerScriptForPrimitiveFactFields != null 
                && !ifVerScriptForPrimitiveFactFields.isEmpty()) {
              ifScriptForPrimitiveFactFields += " && (" + ifVerScriptForPrimitiveFactFields + " || hasChanged )";
            }
    =======

          if (ifScriptForPrimitiveFactFields != null && !ifScriptForPrimitiveFactFields.isEmpty()) {
            if (rule != null && rule.isTriggerApprovalsOnValuesChange() && ifVerScriptForPrimitiveFactFields != null
                && !ifVerScriptForPrimitiveFactFields.isEmpty()) {
              ifScriptForPrimitiveFactFields += " && (" + ifVerScriptForPrimitiveFactFields + " || hasChanged )";
            }
    >>>>>>> THEIRS (select with 'tc') (1575,6)
          } else {
            if(rule != null && rule.isTriggerApprovalsOnValuesChange()) {
              ifScriptForPrimitiveFactFields = "(!idToObjMap || hasChanged)";
    @@
        if(verDataMap != null) {
          idField = verDataMap.get("ID_FIELD");
        }
    <<<<<<< MINE (select with 'mc') (2313,3)
        versionCondition = "(!idToObjMap "
            + "|| (!idToObjMap?.get(i." + idField + ")) || (idToObjMap?.get(i." + idField 
            + ") && i." + factFieldScriptMappingString + subFieldStr + "!=idToObjMap?.get(i."+ idField + ")?." + factFieldScriptMappingString + subFieldStr + ")) ";
    ||||||| ORIGINAL (2334,3)
        versionCondition = "(" + Constants.IS_FIRST_SALES_APPROVAL + " || (idToObjMap?.get(i." + idField
            + ") && i." + factFieldScriptMappingString + subFieldStr + "!=idToObjMap?.get(i." + idField + ")?."
            + factFieldScriptMappingString + subFieldStr + ")) ";
    =======
        versionCondition = "(" + Constants.IS_FIRST_SALES_APPROVAL + " || (idToObjMap?.get(i." + idField + ") && i."
            + factFieldScriptMappingString + subFieldStr + "!=idToObjMap?.get(i." + idField + ")?."
            + factFieldScriptMappingString + subFieldStr + ")) ";
    >>>>>>> THEIRS (select with 'tc') (2334,3)
        return versionCondition;
      }

    @@

        Date addedDate = businessCalendar.add(submitDate, duration);
        long durationSecs = addedDate.getTime() - submitDate.getTime();
    <<<<<<< MINE (select with 'mc') (2330,3)
        expression = "(" + factFieldScriptMapping + ">=" + "order_submit_date) && (" + factFieldScriptMapping + "<="
            + "order_submit_date" + "+" + durationSecs + ")";
        return expression;
    ||||||| ORIGINAL (2351,3)
        expression = "(" + factFieldScriptMapping + "<=" + "order_submit_date ) && (" + durationSecs + "+"
            + factFieldScriptMapping + ">= " + "order_submit_date )";
        return expression;
    =======
        if (hours == 0) {
          return "(new Date(" + factFieldScriptMapping + ").getDay()" + "=="
              + "new Date(order_submit_date).getDay()) && ((" + factFieldScriptMapping + "-" + "order_submit_date"
              + ").abs()" + "<" + "86400000)";
        } else {
          expression = "(" + factFieldScriptMapping + ">" + "order_submit_date) && (" + factFieldScriptMapping + "<"
              + "order_submit_date" + "+" + durationSecs + ")";
          return expression;
        }
    >>>>>>> THEIRS (select with 'tc') (2351,9)
      }

      private String isWithinXWorkingDaysofSubmitForApprovals(List<String> values, String factFieldScriptMapping) {
    @@
              + "order_submit_date" + "+" + durationSecs + ")";
          return expression;
        }
    <<<<<<< MINE (select with 'mc') (2352,5)
        Date addedDate = businessCalendar.add(submitDate, duration);
        long durationSecs = addedDate.getTime() - submitDate.getTime();
        expression = "(" + factFieldScriptMapping + ">=" + "order_submit_date) && (" + factFieldScriptMapping + "<="
            + "order_submit_date" + "+" + durationSecs + ")";
        return expression;
    ||||||| ORIGINAL (2373,5)
        Date addedDate = businessCalendar.add(submitDate, duration);
        long durationSecs = addedDate.getTime() - submitDate.getTime();
        expression = "(" + factFieldScriptMapping + "<=" + "order_submit_date ) && (" + durationSecs + "+"
            + factFieldScriptMapping + ">= " + "order_submit_date )";
        return expression;
    =======
    >>>>>>> THEIRS (select with 'tc') (2382,0)
      }

      private String isWithinXhoursofSubmitForApprovals(List<String> values, String factFieldScriptMapping) {
    <<<<<<< MINE (select with 'mc') (2360,2)
        return "(" + factFieldScriptMapping + ">=" + "order_submit_date) && (" + factFieldScriptMapping + "<="
            + "order_submit_date" + "+" + Long.parseLong(values.get(0)) * 3600000 + ")";
    ||||||| ORIGINAL (2381,2)
        return "(" + factFieldScriptMapping + "<=" + "order_submit_date ) && (" + Long.parseLong(values.get(0)) * 3600000
            + "+" + factFieldScriptMapping + ">=" + "order_submit_date )";
    =======
        if (Long.parseLong(values.get(0)) == 0) {
          return "(new Date(" + factFieldScriptMapping + ").getDay()" + "=="
              + "new Date(order_submit_date).getDay()) && ((" + factFieldScriptMapping + "-" + "order_submit_date"
              + ").abs()" + "<" + "86400000)";
        } else {
          return "(" + factFieldScriptMapping + ">" + "order_submit_date) && (" + factFieldScriptMapping + "<"
              + "order_submit_date" + "+" + Long.parseLong(values.get(0)) * 3600000 + ")";
        }
    >>>>>>> THEIRS (select with 'tc') (2385,8)
      }

      private String isWithinXdayofSubmitForApprovals(List<String> values, String factFieldScriptMapping) {
    <<<<<<< MINE (select with 'mc') (2365,2)
        return "(" + factFieldScriptMapping + ">=" + "order_submit_date) && (" + factFieldScriptMapping + "<="
            + "order_submit_date" + "+" + Long.parseLong(values.get(0)) * 86400000 + ")";
    ||||||| ORIGINAL (2386,2)
        return "(" + factFieldScriptMapping + "<=" + "order_submit_date ) && (" + Long.parseLong(values.get(0)) * 86400000
            + "+" + factFieldScriptMapping + ">=" + "order_submit_date)";
    =======
        if (Long.parseLong(values.get(0)) == 0) {
          return "(new Date(" + factFieldScriptMapping + ").getDay()" + "=="
              + "new Date(order_submit_date).getDay()) && ((" + factFieldScriptMapping + "-" + "order_submit_date"
              + ").abs()" + "<" + "86400000)";
        } else {
          return "(" + factFieldScriptMapping + ">" + "order_submit_date) && (" + factFieldScriptMapping + "<"
              + "order_submit_date" + "+" + Long.parseLong(values.get(0)) * 86400000 + ")";
        }
    >>>>>>> THEIRS (select with 'tc') (2396,8)
      }
@Override
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit, (r) resolved,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options:
```

Here, the first conflict i have (1571,3) i need to do a **mc (mine-conflict)** to keep the original code and remove my changes and for the rest i have use **tc (theirs-conflict)** to keep my changes and remove the original code. 
But i can only enter one option in the terminal.

Could you please help me figure out how i can make multiple changes to same file with different conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

You have basically two options:

- ***Use 'e' (edit):*** In this case an editor will open the file in question and include all the conflict markers that you also saw in the output for `dc`. Then you can search for `<<<<<<<` to find all conflicted areas, resolve them by hand, and once you save and close the editor, you hit `r` to mark that the conflicts for this file were resolved.
- ***Use 'p' (postpone):*** In this case svn will do nothing and proceed with the next file. Once the merging process is finished and you run `svn st`, you will see the files where you hit `p` being marked with a `C` (for conflict). You can then proceed to resolve all conflicts manually as described above. Once finished, you need to execute `svn resolve --accept=working filename` to tell svn that you are finished with conflict resolution.